# Select On React with component

Tags: reactjs, select, components, react-apollo, react-select

I have a problem with this code:

```
const ListItem = ({data: {loading, error, items}}) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>;
  }

  console.log(items)

  return (
    <select>
      <option key='0' value='0' disabled defaultValue>Seleccione un Item</option>
      {items.map(item => <option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.item}</option>)}
    </select>
  );
}

const QUERY_ITEMS = gql`
  query{
    items{
      id
      item
    }
  }
`
const ItemsListWithData = graphql(QUERY_ITEMS)(ListItem);
```

Is a simple Select component, fill by query, but dont appear on index. If i put ul on select its ok, but with select is the problem, I don't have idea whats happening, i gonna add the result with the code. Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szyMy.jpg)

Comment: Where are you using your `ItemsListWithData`? This component by itself doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the `div` that wraps your select. Try to change the class from `input-field` to something like `select-field`

Comment: @MatheusReis thanks a lot, thats was all, I just change the class on div and fix the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Answer posted below. If you want, mark it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `<div>` that is wrapping your `<select>` haves the wrong class.

Change from

```
<div class="input-field col s12"> /* ...  */ </div>
```

To

```
<div class="select-field col s12"> /* ...  */ </div>
```

And everything will work as expected!